# fedora 30 question about .desktop file in application

Tags: linux, fedora

In `/usr/share/applications`, there are many `.desktop` files. But after using Fedora 30, all icons there are not showing and I can only use a text editor to edit them.

Anyone know how to show the icons?

Actually what I want to do is to copy them to my desktop so that I can double click to open the application. but after copying to desktop, still cannot open them except text editor

I can do so in Fedora 25. is it a bug in Fedora 30?